# Using eventlet with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eventlet

I'm using [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) to build a simple website crawler starting from [this example](http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html#producer-consumer-web-crawler).
I would like to use SQLAlchemy to store web pages' content and metadata for further processing. It's possible to use SQLAlchemy along with eventlet? Could anyone provide a simple example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for late reply.

It would really depend on database connection library you use.

- For C extension library, like MySQLdb, Eventlet has [db_pool](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/db_pool.html) module as used in [OpenStack example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~rackspace-titan/nova/sqlalchemy-eventlet/view/head:/nova/db/sqlalchemy/session.py). Basically, it creates a pool of OS threads to execute blocking DB operations. So you can't really have a lot of parallel queries, but most probably your database would not survive them anyway, so that's not an issue.
- For pure Python library, like myconnpy, pg8000, then just call [`eventlet.monkey_patch()`](http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html).
- As a special case, Eventlet supports monkey patching for *psycopg2*. It is a C extension but it is awesome enough to provide IO hooks, so you get best of both worlds. Again, simple call to `monkey_patch()` would do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

The [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/) [Compute (Nova)](http://www.openstack.org/projects/compute/) project uses SQLAlchemy and eventlet, you might be interested in [their approach](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~rackspace-titan/nova/sqlalchemy-eventlet/view/head:/nova/db/sqlalchemy/session.py).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The best approach is to use the eventlet db_pool module with SQLAlchemy NullPoll.